# Trigger parameterised maven release with Curl

Tags: maven, jenkins, curl, jenkins-pipeline

Using following command to perform maven release:

> curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -u user:jenkinscrumb --data-urlencode json='{"parameter":[]}'
> --data-urlencode STAR="three" 
> --data-urlencode releaseVersion="1.5.11" --data-urlencode developmentVersion="1.5.12-SNAPSHOT" 
> --data-urlencode isDryRun=‘true’ 
> "Jenksin-job-URL/m2release/submit"

This command is working properly, but  **STAR="three"** is normal parameter that comes under job-properties. Its value is not getting passed to job.Can anyone guide for passing normal parameter. Regards

Answer (score 0):

USED curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -u user:jenkinscrumb --data-urlencode json='{"parameter":[STAR=$VALUE]}'

AND IT WORKED